# Accessing Matlab MDCS Cluster over SSH

Tags: linux, matlab, ssh, grid, vpn

I just installed Matlab's Distributed Computing Server on a bunch of machines and it works, but only for those physically connected to the cluster's network. For remote access those machines are 2 SSH hops away. How this problem is usually solved? I thought in setting up a VPN, but to me this seems like last resort.

What I want is that everybody in the lab, using their own versions of Matlab, with the correct Toolbox, just run their code in the cluster somewhat effortlessly. I guess I could ask to everybody just tar-ball their files and access a remote installation of matlab, somehow forwarding the GUI session (VNC or X-Forward), but that seem ugly.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set up "remote access" to a cluster running MDCS so that clients without direct access can submit jobs there. The documentation for this starts here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/mdce/configure-parallel-computing-products-for-a-generic-scheduler.html

I'm not quite sure how to configure things so that the submission can work across two SSH connections - the example integration scripts shipping with MDCS all presume only one. However, it should be possible providing that:

1. The client can put the job and task files somewhere the execution nodes can see them
2. The client can trigger the appropriate `qsub` or whatever on the cluster headnode

You might also consider simply contacting MathWorks installation support.